# SwiftUI - Animation when hiding view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to figure out an animation with SwiftUI when showing or hiding a view in a group of a body in a view. I have this code:

```
    var body: some View {

        Group {

            if isIntroShown {
                EAIntroViewContentView()
                .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)))
            }

            if mainhomeMode == .mylists {
                MyLists()
                    .onReceive(publisher) { (payload) in
                        self.toggleMainView()
                    }
            } else {
                CarsHome()
                    .onReceive(publisher) { (payload) in
                        self.toggleMainView()
                    }
            }

        }.onReceive(publisherIntro) { (payload) in
            self.onShowIntroButton()
        }
    }
```

When hiding `EAIntroView`, the transition animation works properly, but the block pops moving up the `mainhomeMode` to the top of the window without animations. How can I hide and show the Intro view making the hide/show event smooth?

Comment: You need to add transition animation to any other view as well in the same way as you did for Intro.

Comment: It is not working in the way I want. I have two views in the body. Ad what I need is that when the upper Intro view is closed, the bottom view change its size to full screen with an animation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, after some tests and the reply of @Boris I have figured out what I need to do.

The code should be like this:

```
    func onShowIntroButton() {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
             isIntroShown.toggle()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {

            VStack{                    
                if isIntroShown {
                    EAIntroViewContentView()
                    .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.linear(duration: 0.5)))
                }

                Spacer()

                if mainhomeMode == .mylists {
                    MyLists()
                        .onReceive(publisher) { (payload) in
                            self.toggleMainView()
                        }

                } else {
                    CarsHome()
                        .onReceive(publisher) { (payload) in
                            self.toggleMainView()
                        }
                }

        }.onReceive(publisherIntro) { (payload) in
            self.onShowIntroButton()
        }
    }
```

I am toggling views with notifications. So the animation must be called from the `toggle()` function.

In this case I have to call the animation when the Intro view is toggled in the function `onShowIntroButton()`.

The `VStak` and the `Spacer()` also made the animation smoother.Hope it helps to other devs.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried anything like this?

```
withAnimation {
    self.toggleMainView()
}
```

Comment: Nop... it is not working. I need add an animation that moves up the lower side of the screen when Intro view is closed.

Comment: But it helped me to find the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe, I didn't understand your task completely, but the idea was to use withAnimation on the toggle function depending on what exactly you want to move. I'm happy my answer helped you to find the solution. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone arriving here because of frustrations with transitions (in my case things seemed fine on appear but animations were missing on disappear), here is a minimal sample and some observations:

##### UI

[image]

##### Code

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var isShown: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                Color.green
                    .zIndex(1)

                if isShown {
                    Color.blue
                        .frame(height: 100)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .opacity))
                        .zIndex(2)
                }
            }
            .animation(.default, value: isShown)

            Button("Button"){ isShown.toggle() }
        }
    }
}
```

##### Observations:

- Notice here I intentionally do not use `withAnimation` (aka implicit animations), but rather I use explicit an animation modifier at the appropriate view and reference the relevant value. In general it is better to be as specific and tightly scoped with animations as possible, to avoid unexpected over-animating.
- Notice the transition modifier is applied to the "bottom bar", whereas the animation modifier is applied to the superview. Notice also that transitions themselves support an animation modifier (i.e. this is valid code: `.transition(.<someTransition>.animation(.default)`), but this won't behave correctly in our case.
- Finally, I was really struggling to understand why it seemed like 'on disappear' my view does not animate - turns out it *was* animating, but was "jumping" behind the background (here `Color.green`) at the start. This is why I use the `zIndex` modifiers.